# Counter-intuitive practice problem to group and operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Determine if $\ast$  is a binary operation and if$ \left ( G,\ast \right ) $is a group. Explain.

> Question: $G=\mathbb{N}$ and $a\ast b$ is the smallest integer greater than both a and b.

For instance, if a=4 and b=5 then $a\ast$ b=6

> Definition: G is a set. A binary operation on a set G is a function that assigns to each ordered pair of element $\left \{ a,b \right \}\subseteq G$ an element $a \in G$

Indeed, $\ast$ is a binary operation. 
$\forall a,b\in G$
$a\ast b=c$ such that $c>a$ and $c>b\ \exists c \in G=\mathbb{N}$

> Group axiom:
>
> Associativity:
>   $\forall a,b,c \in G$
>
> $\left ( a\ast b \right )\ast c=a\ast \left ( b\ast c \right )$
>
> Identity element:
>
> $\forall a \in G$
>
> $a\ast e=e\ast a=a$
>
> Inverse element:
>
> $\forall a \in G$, $\exists b \in G$
>
> $a\ast b=b\ast a=e$

Proving G is a group is a bit tricky.

Say, $a\ast b$=$b\ast a$ then $b=e$

$a > b=e$ but $a\ngtr a$

so by this counterexample, G is not a group.

Does my above explanation suffice? Or can further explanation be built upon?

Comment: Your *'Inverse element axiom'* seems absurd. Does really $a*b=e$ for each pair of $a$ and $b$ arguments?!

Comment: @CiaPan made the correct. Too hard to keep a straight head when typing in latex.

Comment: Where do you read on the axioms "$a*b=b*a$ then $b=e$"? This is pure invention, nothing to deal with group axioms.

Comment: You can just show that there exists no $e\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a\ast e=a$ because that would imply $a>a$, which must be false

Comment: To have at least associativity and an identity element, replace "greater than" by "greater than or equal to", that is $a * b = \max\{a,b\}$. It is still not a group, though.

Answer (score 5):

Your explanation does not make any sense to me, but it's not a group. Suppose $e$ is an identity, then $e\ast e = e$. On the other hand $e\ast e = e+1$ by definition of $\ast$. Thus $e=e+1$ which is obviously a contradiction.

$\ast$ is also not associative, because $(4\ast2)\ast3=5\ast3=6$ and $4\ast(2\ast3) = 4\ast4=5$.

Addendum: The inverse element is undefined, since no identity exists.

Comment: And the inverse element is undefined, since identity element does not exist.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks, will add that.